# Why is $L(\mathbb{R})$  just the set of multiplication maps?

Tags: linear-algebra

It makes sense that the only linear transformations on $\mathbb{R}$ would be maps of the form $x\mapsto ax$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$. But how do we know these maps are *all* the possible linear transformations on the reals? Is there a way to prove that there isn't some weird function out there that just happens to be linear but isn't just a multiplication function?

Comment: Try taking the derivative of a linear transformation from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: As soon as you know where one non-zero element e.g. $1$ is going you know where the rest must go by linearity.

Comment: @Jacob Schlather: Overkill. One does not know *a priori* that a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable (although this is, of course, true). In order to prove this, it suffices to verify differentiability at $0$ by linearity but once you start working along these lines you are already making the problem much too complex.

Comment: @Amitest Good point. I tend to take it for granted. It is of course much simpler to just look at at T(1).

Comment: @Jacob: I removed an earlier comment similar to Amitesh's because your proposal doesn't help at all. After differentiating you're left with a linear map which you want to show not to be of erratic nature...

Comment: I suppose that we are implicitly assuming "$\Bbb R$-linear". Else, things become pretty intricate.

Comment: @Andrea In fact, I have noted some variations of this question in the exercises presented in my answer below. Of course, one can use the axiom of choice to construct non-trivial (i.e., non-$\mathbb{R}$-linear) $\mathbb{Q}$-linear maps of $\mathbb{R}$ (as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $T$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself. Let $a = T(1)$. Then for any $x \in R$ we have $T(x) = T(x \cdot 1) = x \cdot T(1) = ax$ and so $T$ is just multiplication by $a$. So there is no weird function that is linear but isn't a multiplication function; any linear function from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself is a multiplication function.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a linear map. Note that $f$ is completely determined by the image of a basis, so in our particular case we have $f(x) = f(x\cdot 1) = x f(1)\quad$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Could someone please explain the downvote?

Comment: I hope you don't mind; there seemed to be an overlap at the end of your expression $f(x)$, and the subsequent "for"...so I simply added some space between the end of the former and start of the latter.  Perhaps it was just my webpage's rendering...

Comment: It actually worked for me... But if it helps you it should be fine, I guess :D

Answer (score 1):

An $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ corresponds to a $1\times 1$-matrix. I challenge you to find $1\times 1$-matrices that don't have the form $(a_{11})$ for some scalar $a_{11}\in\mathbb{R}$ :) This is multiplication by $a_{11}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $1\in\mathbb{R}$ is a "vector" and that $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is a "scalar" in the following computation: $f(a)=f(a\cdot 1)=af(1)$; the $\cdot$ denotes multiplication of a "scalar" by a "vector" (which, of course, is the same as multiplication of real numbers and hence the $\cdot$ is omitted in the entity after the final equality). If $c=f(1)\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f(a)=ca$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and thus $f$ equals multiplication by a fixed real number.

***Exercise 1***: Prove that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f(z)=cz$ for all $z\in\mathbb{R}$ and some $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

***Exercise 2***: If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable and if $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, then prove that $f$ is continuous. [*Real and Complex Analysis* (Second Edition) by Walter Rudin, Chapter 8, Exercise 24]

***Exercise 3***: Prove (using the axiom of choice) that there exist real *discontinuous* functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. [*Real and Complex Analysis* (Second Edition) by Walter Rudin, Chapter 8, Exercise 24]

I hope this helps!